# Syntax errors when setting variable to lock object using x = threading.Lock()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Whilst reading into thread and sockets in python I found a resource that basically did what I wanted. I changed it a little to suit my needs and then worked to rewrite and functionate it to ensure I understood what I was doing.

One element however I have not changed in any way whatsoever and it gives me a syntax error.

As per the title, the line is simply:

```
global printlock = threading.Lock()
```

And in one file it works seamlessly and in my version, it returns:

```
global print_lock=threading.Lock()
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried changing the spacing just in case but can see no obvious reason for the issues creating this lock object. Any ideas?

```
def establish_connection(s):
    while True:
        print("Waiting for connections...")
        connection, clientaddr = s.accept()
        log_connection(clientaddr)
        printlock.acquire()
        print("Connected to: " + str(clientaddr))
        start_new_thread(tfunction, (connection,))
    s.close()
```

It is essentially used so it doesn't crumble on itself when people connect and it'll process a single request at a time but since making a new file it just hits a syntax error for no apparent reason

Comment: Didn't seem to carry across well but in terminal, it looks to point directly at =

Comment: Where is that line in the function you posted?

Comment: I'm surprised that you could find a file in which this invalid syntax wouldn't cause an error. Could you maybe share it?

Comment: Including global caused problems in and of itself and wasn't actually required. Didn't realise the other file was working without this. 

The actual issue was just tab/spaces mismatched having copied from atom into my ssh client to test

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a variable in a `global` statement, it's just used for declaring the variable. Split it into two statements:

```
global printlock
printlock = threading.Lock()
```

Comment: Looks like the global aspect was an issue but the actual problem was a mismatch between tabs and spaces as it was partially written in nano and partially in atom.Cleaned that up and returned to the original: printlock = threading.Lock()

And it worked no issues